# ErrorItemNotFound error for message resource, but found when OData filter applied

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

We're experiencing an issue with some of our users in which our HTTP requests to the Graph API are resulting in an `ErrorItemNotFound` error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "ErrorItemNotFound",
    "message": "The specified object was not found in the store., The process failed to get the correct properties.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "c65a51b6-163c-4b68-9cf5-976b3738af0c",
      "date": "2019-05-20T20:35:52"
    }
  }
}
```

We're attempting to obtain a message resource through the [messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=cs#http-request) endpoint.

We've been making attempts to query for a particular message for a user with the `/me/messages/{id}` endpoint. A simple query for a message using the message ID returns that error.

However, a subsequent request to the [list messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=cs) endpoint yields the message. This query supplies an OData `$filter` parameter. The message ID has not changed and the message hasn't moved.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages
 ?$filter=(createdDateTime ge 2019-05-03T17:56:58Z) 
 and (createdDateTime le 2019-05-03T17:57:13Z)
```

**Note**: the message could still be found without supplying the filter. I don't imagine that your recommendation is that we make requests for more data than we need and have the client (end-user/consumer) filter. Right?

It is incredibly odd that the API can't find a message using a "membership"/get item query by its unique identifier, but can when using a "collection"/list items query. This seems to be a bug. I saw a similar issue to which your team has not responded to in the documentation repository on GitHub.

This could be replicated in your Graph Explorer or any other HTTP client (curl, Postman). This seems like a bug.

Comment: Trying to understand how the `$filter` bit is relevant. Are you saying it doesn't list this message if you don't include a filter? Also, please include a code sample showing how you're calling the API. Error messages on their own are generally not very helpful.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur there really isn't much of a code sample. You can use any HTTP client. I made attempts with HTTParty (a Ruby HTTP client) as well as Postman only setting an Authorization header that included a user's token, `"Bearer {token}"` and a `GET` request to: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/{message_id}`. The subsequent request is not performed specifying the `message_id`, only a filter for the window in which that message was created. Not supplying a filter, would, of course, return all the user's messages and the message could be found in that collection

Comment: Note that the original post contains an inner error with a request ID should you want to search for it in your logs. I could also supply screenshots, but am unsure how I could provide a code sample. Also, we're in contact with Frank Hu on your team at the moment. I do appreciate the help, though, Marc.

Comment: Oh, the `$filter` bit isn't that relevant as it only helps reduce the size of the collection of messages returned such that we could search for the message we're looking for a bit more easily which is why I noted that it isn't required

Comment: Just to clarify, Stack Overflow isn't a Microsoft site/property/company. It's a volunteer community of developers helping developers. Since you have access to professional support and already have a ticket with them, I would start there. They have more resources than most of the community here.

Comment: I’m not sure why you felt that comment was necessary. I’m well aware of that. Perhaps you weren’t aware that members of your team are directing users here after closing issues against the GiHub repo for API docs. The organization that I’m with does not have paid support and the issue I’m reporting may be an issue affecting several users or tenants. I’ve provided as much detail as I could short of a video chat. Frank responded to my email saying you’d provide the support necessary as this is your domain...